# Можно ли отключать slick На разных разрешениях?

Tags: javascript, jquery, адаптивная-верстка, responsive, slick.js

Подскажи есть ли возможность отключать карусель slick на каких либо разрешениях? К примеру если его инициализировать то на десктопах чтобы карусель работала а на мобильных чтобы она отключалась.

Comment: Проверяйте разрешение экрана и если подходящее - то инициализируйте плагин) Что у вас не получилось? Узнать разрешение экрана ?

Comment: @Moonvvell Не смотрел на решение проблемы таким образом, думал что возможно есть какой либо метод который отключает плагин на определенном breakpointe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В свойстве `responsive` вы задаёте массив объектов с брейкпоинтами. На одном из нужных вам брейкпоинтов надо свойству `settings` вместо объекта передать значение `unslick`.

Из [официальной документации](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) (листайте к блоку **Responsive Display**):

```
responsive: [
{
  breakpoint: 1024,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 600,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
}
// You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
// settings: "unslick"
// instead of a settings object
]
```

Comment: Пробовал так делать не получалось поэтому решил задать вопрос. Видимо я не правильно понял как работают брейкпоинты, думал там задается min-width а оказывается max-width, в любом случае благодарю за пояснение. P.S. Теперь не нужно использовать конструкцию по высчитыванию ширины девайса))